# Converting std::int to System::Single

Tags: c++-cli

Apologies if there's an answer out there already; but all I seem to be getting is a bunch of "I want to turn my 1 into a 1.0" chaff from my Google searches.

First things first. No, I'm *not* talking about a simple Convert::ToSingle() call. Rather, I need to convert the representation of the data to a System::Single.

So in other words, I'd like to take `int myInt = 1065353216;`, and the result should be something like `1.000`. I know the pure c++ method would be something like `float myFloat=*(float *)&myInt;`;but I need the managed version.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in C++/CLI, you can do it the same way as you do in C++: `float myFloat=*(float*)&myInt;`

In pure managed-land, there are built-in methods to do this for double & Int64 ([`DoubleToInt64Bits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits.aspx) and [`Int64BitsToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.int64bitstodouble.aspx), but not for single & Int32. However, if you look at the implementation of those methods ([MS Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/db20ea77a561c0ac.html)), you'll see that they're doing the exact same thing as you have listed, so that's also the managed way to do it. The only difference is if you do it in C#, you have to tag the method as `unsafe`.

Comment: Turns out the issue was nothing more than Intellisense getting confused about a managed int array. Once I declared an int with a value from the array, and used that variable in the cast, it worked fine. Thanks for your time!